# jest enzyme | testing Promise in component function passes but throws an error

Tags: reactjs, promise, jestjs

I have a container where I have a function which makes an API request using `fetch`:

```
updateBooks = books => this.setState({ books });

getBooks = keyword => fetch(`${googleBooksSearchAPI}${keyword}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myJson => this.updateBooks(myJson.items))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

I'm trying to write tests for it using `fetch-mock`:

```
it('getBooks works', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<BookContainer />);
    const mockData = { items: bookListObj };
    fetchMock.get(googleBooksSearchAPI, mockData);

    wrapper.instance().getBooks('dun');
    expect(wrapper.state().books).toEqual(bookListObj);

    fetchMock.restore();
});
```

All tests show as passed, but still, I can see this error:

```
console.log app/components/BookContainer.js:20
      error FetchError {
        name: 'FetchError',
        message: 'invalid json response body at undefined reason: Unexpected end of JSON input',
        type: 'invalid-json' }
```

if I remove `catch` from fetch it shows the message like this:

```
(node:5094) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at undefined reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
(node:5094) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:5094) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

How to remove it?

Comment: What is fetchMock? Where is getBooks called? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `fetchMock` is, as written, - `fetch-mock`. `getBooks` is called in `componentDidUpdate`, I don't think it is important from this test point of view. I'm testing just this function

Comment: MCVE is required by SO rules to avoid long negotiations about what should be posted and what shouldn't. I suppose the problem here is that `getBooks` is called before `fetch` is mocked or it's not mocked for some other reason, but I cannot confirm this without seeing the component.

Comment: Perhaps, you need to apply keyword to fetch mock fetchMock.get(`${googleBooksSearchAPI}dyn`, mockData)